# Python NET start a windows application

Tags: python, .net, python-2.7, com, python.net

How to start a windows application like notepad using python NET ? This is my source code with python 2.7.13:

```
C:\Python27>python.exe
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import clr
>>> import System
>>> type = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notepad.Application")
>>> System.Activator.CreateInstance(type)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: activationContext
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
```

Comment: can you check if `type` is not `None`? Are you sure about ProgID="Notepad.Application"? It returns null for me. Also `type` is reserved keyword in Python.

Comment: This is an old example , I think is internal python error with the new version of this package System and instantiate way .

Comment: i did not understand you

Comment: My problem is an old example and maybe this is the reason to got errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ProgID="Notepad.Application" COM object on my machine, pythonnet works with other COM objects:

```
>>> import clr
>>> import System
>>> type1=System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application")
>>> type1
<System.RuntimeType object at 0x02ABEE10>
>>> System.Activator.CreateInstance(type1)
<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass object at 0x02AD11D0>
```

Comment: So just Excel can be start it with this? What COM objects can be used with my example?

Comment: You can instantiate any COM object using this. I just gave Excel example because it is very popular.

Comment: I know in theory how COM objects work, but I'm not sure that it works with python and this python module. Need more info and help.